# Why isn't my box flexing to the end of its container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't figure out why the red box in the image above isn't flexing to attach to the end of the outer green box. I want my logo to flex to sit at the start of the nav box and the navigation items to flex to sit at the end of the nav box.

[image: flexbox example]

```css
nav {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 120px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

ul {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 5vw;
}

.individual_nav_item {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: thin;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #445077;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.individual_nav_item:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="./images/random.jpeg" alt="logo" class="logo" />
  <ul>
    <a href="/index.html" class="individual_nav_item">Home</a>
    <a href="/about_us.html" class="individual_nav_item">About Us</a>
    <a href="#" class="individual_nav_item">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" class="individual_nav_item">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the nav flexbox content should be set to space-between :

```
nav{
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content : space-between ;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 120px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```